# Fluid width fixed position

Tags: css, css-position, fluid-layout

Imagine:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where:

- `.outer` is part of a column structure, and its width is a percentile and therefore fluid.
- `.inner` represents a `fixed` position element that should fill with a 100% width the `.outer` element. However its position vertically remains the same, therefore `fixed`.

I’ve tried to implement this layout with the following CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: %;
}
.inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, `.inner` does not calculate its width as a percentage of its `relative` parent. Instead it fills the full width of the window/document. Attempting any `left` or `right` properties result in the same parent-ignoring qualities.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: position: fixed is always and always "relative" to the browser window/view port and never "relative" to a positioned (absolute or relative) parent/ancestor.

Comment: "Is there any way around this?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846161/fixed-positioned-div-within-a-relative-parent-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976048/fixed-position-layer-div-in-relation-to-its-parent-div-with-overflowauto

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/position-fixed-relative-to-parent-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/css-fixed-position-but-relative-to-container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431358/how-to-make-an-element-with-fixed-position-relative-to-its-parent-not-the-whole

Comment: The third solution of @Jawad is actually brilliant !

Comment: I also used @Jawad 3rd answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/position-fixed-relative-to-parent-div )

Comment: just because you want an element to have a non changing height / vertical position does mean that the element has to be marked as fixed. the fiddle provided by @Ilan Biala clearly demonstrates a working example

Answer (score 7):

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: %;
}
.inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Was having this issue, and this actually solved it. 

For reference, the `inherit` property is _inheriting_ the width set by its nearest parent.

Answer (score 4):

`position: fixed` is always relative to the window/browser, thus it cannot be used to solve your problem. Fixed positioning removes the element from the natural order of the DOM, and thus does not remain within your outer div anymore, hence why it takes the full width of the browser and not of your container. What you need to use is `position: absolute` to place `.inner` relative to `.outer`. You'll be able to position your element as well as have its width be contained by the `.outer` div.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

.inner {
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;

}

Comment: Left and right here are in relation to the document, not the container div as is desired though?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed elements take only absolute values as width. If your parent container is fluid (width is a percentage), you need to set the width of the fixed element dynamically. You need to get the width of the wrapping container and set it on the sticky element.

CSS

```
.outer {width: 25%;}
.inner {position: fixed;}
```

JS

```
var fixedWidth = $('.outer').css('width');
$('.inner').css('width', fixedWidth);
```

Additionally, you can add an event listener in case window resizes.

JS

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
function resize() {
    var fixedWidth = $('.outer').css('width');
    $('.inner').css('width', fixedWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVuTY/12/) that i made that illustrates the fix for your problem, you can use this code exactly as it does what you want.

Comment: How is your JSFiddle related to position:fixed?

Comment: I gave a fix, I didn't say it relates to `position:fixed;`. It's related to his problem and my answer proposes a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is always relative to viewport/browser window, not to ancestors.

Comment: This doesn't hold anymore once `transform` is applied in modern browsers...

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVuTY/135/) ?

```
.outer {
    width: 20%;
    height: 1200px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    float: left;
}
.inner {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: orange;
    right: 75%;
    left: 5%;
}
```